# Which is the best redirection method used in html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, href, location-href

I have seen `location.href`, `window.open`, `window.location`, etc for redirection.

1. I want to know which is the best method and works on every device.
2. One more thing if I have using setTimer and loads the script after loads the page elements which is the best method?

Please treat answer for both 1 and 2 question separately and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post an *entire* question in bold, that just makes it harder to read. Also, if you have two unrelated questions then please post them separately. `window.open()` opens a new window (oddly enough), so isn't really a redirection method and isn't comparable to setting the `location.href` of the *current* window.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = 'URL';
```

is the standard implementation for changing the current window's location.

*document.locatio*n is a (deprecated but still present) read-only string property, replaced by *document.url*.

`window.location` also affects to the frame,

the best form i found is:

```
parent.window.location.href
```

And the worse is:

```
parent.document.URL
```

I did a massive browser test, and some rare IE with several plugins get undefined with the second form.